# Reading combinations of string and integer from file in C

Tags: c, stdio, file-read

I am novice to C langugage, so please bear with me. I've tried to read a file which contains strings but output obtained is single character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define CALLOC(num, type) ((char*)calloc (num, sizeof(char)))
#define FREE(addr) (free((void*) (addr)))

int i, count;
char *x, *y, *z;

int main (void) 

{

FILE *stream;
if ( (stream = fopen ( "test.txt", "r" )) == NULL )
{ printf ("Cannot read the new file\n");
exit (1);
}

count = 3;

x=CALLOC(count, char);
y=CALLOC(count, char);
z=CALLOC(count, char);


for ( i=0; i<count; i++ ) 
{ fscanf (stream,"%c %c %c", &x[i], &y[i], &z[i]);
printf ("\n %d %c %c %c ", i, x[i], y[i], z[i]);
}

FREE(x);
FREE(y);
FREE(z);

fclose (stream);

}
```

Input test.txt file contains

```
1 ab 1
2 aa 5
1 cc 1
```

current output

```
 0 1 a b
 1   1 2
 2   a a
```

Expected output

```
 0 1 ab 1
 1 2 aa 5
 2 1 cc 1
```

I doubt whether I should use a character array but it seems not working and I feel reading a int using char is acceptable. Here I require the expected output, for this any method/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: really shouldnt be casting the pointer to free ( its pointless ). also no need to cast the calloc. and should move the global variables into main ( theres no need for them to be global )

Comment: [Do not cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%c` reads in only one char. So it's not going to read `ab` as a single char. Your lines in file and your formats don't correctly to read an entire line.

A simple approach is to use `fgets()` and print the entire line:

```
char line[256];
i = 0;

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stream))
{
   printf ("%d %s", i, line);
   i++;
}
```

By the way, macros for `calloc` and `free` are unnecessary. They really don't make the code any easier to read than directly using those functions.

And the [casts in them are also unnecessary](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

Comment: It is printing as expected but it no more stores the values in any variable (such as x,y or z) that I can access later, I am trying to access only the second column ie "ab, aa, cc" is there any way to obtain?

Comment: If you need to look at values, then use `sscanf()` on `line`. But you have to use `%s` read strings such as `ab` and ensure the buffer you have can store as many bytes.

Comment: It's not only unneccessary but also not recommended http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714 I've never seen any one uses `free` with cast

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I have seen it before. But I don't recommend it in my answers/comments due to its exaggeration, authoritative-sounding and inflammatory nature. Instead I would always link to comp.lang.c (linked in the answer) page which explains quite clearly about the effects of casting without missing any necessary detail. Casting free is a pre-standard artifact where free used to take a `char*`. I have seen it old code. Still some (incorrectly) do it out of habit.

Comment: @BlueMoon as per the inputs I have removed the unnecessary casting and free. Since I am coding for a bigger puzzle I have used global variables so that I can access as and when required now I've used "sscanf(buffer, "%d%s%d", &line, hex, &ch);" and found working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have the scan file. %c read a 8bit value. You scanned 3 char, but the file is contain 4 characters. If you don't use to be the value of the x, y, z I don't understand why use malloc.

Here a working source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int count,i;
  char w,x,y,z;
  FILE *stream;
  if((stream = fopen("test.txt","r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot read the new file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  count = 3;
  for(i=0;i<count;++i) {
    fscanf(stream,"%c %c%c %c\n",&w,&x,&y,&z);
    printf("%d %c %c%c %c\n",i,w,x,y,z);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i=0;i<count; i++ ) 
        { 
            fscanf (stream,"%s %s %s", x, y, z);
            printf ("\n %d %s %s %s ", i, x, y, z);  
        }
```

You can modify your  loop to this.This loop will read file until `end of file` and you have to use `%s` as `ab` is a string not charater so it  can't be stored in a char variable.

Comment: `feof` here is not used correctly; see explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg  Yes ,thank you for correcting me . I modified the loop as per OP's need .